# Topology qustion

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$={$a,b,c$} with Topology $T$ = {{$a,b$}, {$b,c$}, {$b$}, $\emptyset$, $X$}

Let $A$={$c$}, what are the interior, closure and boundary of $A$ in this case?

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

As far as I can see the only possible options for interior are {$c$} and $\emptyset$. With the latter being what I think is correct. But then the closure, is it one of {$a,c$} or {$c$}? I don't know whether {$a,c$} is actually an option or not.

Comment: See [Interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) : "the union of all open subsets of that set."  What are the *open* sets that are subsets of $A = \{ c \}$ ? Only $\emptyset$.

Comment: $\{ a, b \}$ is *open*; thus, its complement $\{ c \}$ will be *closed*. The [Closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) is "the intersection of all closed sets containing that set." Thus $\{ c \}$ is its closure.

Comment: I can see that {$c$} is closed, but is {$a,c$} something to consider or not. Is this open or closed? Does it contain {$c$}?

Comment: $\{ a,c \}$ is *closed*, because it is the complement of $\{ b \}$, which is *open*. The closed are : $\emptyset, X, \{ a \}, \{ c \}$ and $\{ a,c \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interior is empty and closure of $A$ is $A$ itself (because the complement is open). Therefore the boundary is also $A$.

Note that the only point $c$ of $A$ is not an interior point because the only open sets containing $c$ also contain $b$.